# No US HAWAII time zone in Momentjs or nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

How can I set US HAWAII time zone with Momentjs. Hawaii Time zone is UTC-10 and US Pacific time is UTC-8. 
There is a configuration in moment for US Pacific time but not for Hawaii UTC-10, Is there any way to achieve it for UTC-10

```
moment.tz(seats[i].activitydatetime, 'US/Pacific').format()
```

Comment: `Pacific/Honolulu` - for future reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the timezone "Pacific/Honolulu"